# Apparmor: lxc-containers contains no profile

Tags: 18.04, lxc, apparmor

I ran an audit on my ubuntu 18.04 ec2 instance against **Ubuntu 18.04 CIS benchmark**. The issue was reported as " Ensure all AppArmor Profiles are enforcing" and it was Failed.

When I was investigating resolving this issue, I noticed **lxc-containers** contains no profile.

```
$ aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/*
Profile for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions not found, skipping
Profile for /etc/apparmor.d/cache not found, skipping
Profile for /etc/apparmor.d/disable not found, skipping
Profile for /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain not found, skipping
Profile for /etc/apparmor.d/local not found, skipping
Profile for /etc/apparmor.d/lxc not found, skipping
Setting /etc/apparmor.d/lxc-containers to enforce mode.

ERROR: /etc/apparmor.d/lxc-containers contains no profile
```

[image: lxc-containers contains no profile]

I couldn't find enough information to resolve this.

I found this article but it is not related to resolving this issue: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/containers-lxc/11526

currently, I have no idea whether to verify this false positive or resolve this by creating a profile.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste info into the body of the question.

Comment: @David I just updated text.